# Updating Sql from Data in the List C# Console

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, console-application

I'm Running a query and putting that data into the List, now i want to run a update query on the sql from the data in the list.

```
Console.WriteLine("SQL connection okay");               
connection.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Opened");
string sql = "select GUID,GUSMStID  from SMS_Table where senddate < GETDATE () and Status ='Active' and SMSType='MMS'";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))    
{
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var SMSlist = new SMSList();
            SMSlist.GUID = reader["GUID"].ToString();
            SMSlist.GUSMSID = reader["GUSMSID"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Fetching SMS...", ConsoleColor.Blue);
            ListofSMS.Add(SMSlist);                               
        }
    Console.WriteLine("Fetching SMS Completed", ConsoleColor.Cyan);
```

so i have set of GUID in the list now i want to update SMS_table using those GUIDs, how to do that?

Comment: Well you seem to know how to use the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` classes. And I'm betting you know that in addition to `select` statements, you can do `insert` or `update` or `delete` statements. Seems like you have all the necessary ingredients to do this yourself. Why don't you try it?

Comment: i know i have to use a loop again to run the update query, cause the needed GUID's in the list i want to update the table using a where GUID='the GUID's in the list' please give some support @mason

Comment: I did give you some support. I told you that you seem to have the necessary knowledge to do it yourself. You've got all the right classes, you know your where clause, you know you need a loop. Put that knowledge to use!

Comment: Marc, i'm stuck 
**for (int i = 0; i <= ListofSMS.Count; i++) {

                                

                                string sql = "UPDATE SMStablet SET Status='Expired' where GUID=@SMSID ";

                            } ** @mason

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SqlCommand` for inserts/updates using the `ExecuteNonQuery(`) method.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

for (int i = 0; i < ListofSMS.Count; i++)
    command.CommandText += string.Format("update SMS_Table set someField=yourValue where GUID={0};", ListofSMS[i].ToString());

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The above is a really simple sql update statement you can run on your table. You can manually write your insert/update statements in sql and execute them in the manner above. There may be a syntax error in my sql, but the above is the should give you the general idea of what you need to do.

Comment: hi thank you for your support, my GUID's are in the list, can you explain the "guidlookup"? @jsmith

Comment: It's meant to be whatever your GUID in the list is. Updated based on some of your other comments to try and help convey what you're looking for. :)

Comment: perfect:) how to it get those GUID's in the list to this parameter, i know how to add a parameter to the query, i want to know how to get that GUID from the list to this @jsmith

Comment: Use a `foreach(ListItem in SMSList)` and unpack it or get the `GUID` of the `SMSList` item in `ListItem`.